# Cannot Reference Protected Component

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components

I develop a **"Lightning Component"**. I want to use a **Custom Label (Protected Component)**. The reason for protection, because there is a deletion possibility in the middle of development.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_protected_components.htm

**I tried**

- Create a "Custom Label"
- Enable the "Protected Component"
- Using Custom Labels in Lightning Component

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm

**results**

- The development organization error do not. Errors Occur only in the installation organization
- Error Message is "$Label.namespace.labelName does not exist: Cannot Reference Protected Component namespace__labelName"
- NG: Use in Custom "Lightning Component"
  {!$Label.namespace.labelName}
- OK: Use in Visualforce
  {!$Label.labelName}

Comment: Did the custom label that you are using get installed into the packaging org? By weird design, sometimes referenced custom labels are not packaged (see [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DuX7AAK)). Can you use it in a VF page in your package and see it in the VF page in the subscriber org? The packaging and installation process should automatically translate all references of $Label.yourCustomLabel to $Label.yourNs.yourCustomLabel to insert the namespace, but perhaps this is similar to the design of the apex:composition not supporting custom labels.

Comment: @PeterKnolle san Thank's. This is not an issue?
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index

Comment: Did you reference in another component such as a VF page? If not, it won't get automatically added. Also, with custom labels in Lightning it looks like you have to use the namespace in your code and not rely on an automatic transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a +6 yo question. Here is how I solved it today:

In your packaging org go to Custom Labels, edit the label and uncheck the box "Protected Component". Once you create a new package version and install it, the error is no more.

[image]

Comment: Be very careful when doing this.  By making the label unprotected, you'll never be able to delete it from your managed package, which is a specific requirement of this question.